# What can we conclude about $E(X\mid Y,Z)?$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I have a question about conditional expectation. Suppose that $X, Y, Z$ are three random variables.
If there is a constant such that
$$E(X\mid Y)<C,$$
what can we conclude about
$$E(X\mid Y,Z)?$$

Is $E(X\mid Y,Z)<C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't conclude anything. Suppose we are picking an arbitrary complex number. $Y$ is the probability of choosing a real number. $X,Z$ are both the random variable that is $1$ if the chosen number is rational, otherwise $0$.

Thus, any positive $C$ bounds $E(X\mid Y)$, but $E(X\mid Y,Z)=1$.